# finding a linux distribution that will run on sparc cpu

Tags: linux, solaris, java, sparc

We have a server that runs on Solaris using the sparc CPU.

What we want to do is run linux on sparc.

Is there any distribution that will allow linux to run on a sparc CPU?

The reason is because we want to completely remove the Solaris O/S and install linux. Then install the JVM that runs on Linux using the sparc cpu.

I did look at CentOS, but I couldn't find a release that would run on sparc.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Which CPU/machine?

Comment: Did you want to include BSD in your possibilities? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian.  See http://www.debian.org/ports/sparc/ for information.

Comment: I did check distrowatch. And the architecture is supported for Debian. So I might install ubuntu server LTS. However, about the Java Virtual Machine? Will that run under sparc?

Comment: See http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sparc/java/

Answer (score 3):

Gentoo: Some project information can be found here -> http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/sparc/index.xml